# Django ManyToManyField that only works one way

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have my models set up as follows:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    related_products = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='related_products')
```

As you can see, the relation is to itself. Now, lets say I have 3 products in my database: A, B, C.

B's related product is C. Now, if I add B to the related product for A, then B's related product changes from **C** to **A and C**.

I don't want this, I want the change to only go one way. If I add B to A's related products, then B's related product won't change. Hope this is clear.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`related_name='+'` use this. this will sort out your problem i guess.
refer documentation for [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) backword relation.

Comment: This doesn't work. It still goes both ways unfortunately.

Comment: i got it, set `symmetrical = False` in field options. by default it is True.

Comment: glad, happy to help :)

Comment: @SumeetKumar Would you be able to edit your answer to reflect your comment. Thanks